# Timer0 in PIC18F26J50

Tags: pic, timer, c18

I have a PIC18F26J50 and I want timer0 to output a 1Hz signal on RA6. I'm now getting ~800Hz with my current setup. Clock is 48MHz / 4 = 12MHz on RA6 (if INTOSCPLLO is enabled). Compiler is C18.

Here is my code, which is wrong obviously and I need to find out what the problem is and understand how this stuff works.

```
BYTE Timer0Init( WORD wTimeInterval )
{
UINT16 timerRegValue;
INT8 rc = ERROR_INVALID_COMMAND;

const UINT16 timerPeriodInSeconds = 1;
const UINT32 clockFreq = GetSystemClock();
const UINT16 prescalerValue = (256);
const UINT16 resolution = 65536;   

interruptsDisableAll();

//! configure the timer 0 for 16 bit mode and preescaler of 256
T0CONbits.TMR0ON    = TMR0ON_OFF;           //! turn off
T0CONbits.T08BIT    = T08BIT_LEN_16;        //! select the 16 bit mode
T0CONbits.T0CS      = T0CS_INT;             //! internal clock 
T0CONbits.T0SE      = 0;                    
T0CONbits.PSA       = PSA_PREESC_ASSIGN;    //! use the prescaler    
T0CONbits.T0PS      = T0PS_PREESC_1_256;    //! 1/? prescaler

timerRegValue = ( clockFreq * timerPeriodInSeconds );
timerRegValue = (UINT16)( timerRegValue/(4*prescalerValue) );
timerRegValue = resolution - timerRegValue;

reloadValue_ = timerRegValue;

writeTMR0Register( timerRegValue );

INTCONbits.TMR0IF   = 0;                 //! clear the interrupt flag
INTCONbits.TMR0IE   = 1;    

T0CONbits.TMR0ON = TMR0ON_ON;            //! turn on

interruptsEnableAll();

rc = ERROR_SUCCESS;

return rc;
}
```

I got this calculations from a formula I found on the internet. I read and re-read the datasheet and the calculations seems ok. So what is the problem anyway?

Any help is really appreciated!

Thank you.

Comment: `timerRegValue` is 16 bits, so `timerRegValue = ( clockFreq * timerPeriodInSeconds )` is going to overflow (assuming `clockFreq` is 48,000,000). Try using 32 bits for all calculations right up until you need to store in smaller registers.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming 16 bit tmr0, the offset should bee set like this

Tmr0 = -(fxtal / 4 / prescaler)

At least one of them needs to be 32 type.

For 8bit tmr0, it has to bee done over multiple Isr invokation. The trick there is to only load the counter once.

edit: here is one of many ways to do the trick mentioned above.

```
//tmr0 isr handle
void my_isr(void) {
    if (tmr0_cnt) {                         //not running out yet
        tmr0_cnt -= 0x100;                  //update tmr0
    } else {
        TMR0 = -TMR_PR;                     //load the TMR0 counter with the initial offset
        tmr0_cnt = TMR_PR &~0xfful;         //initialize the counter - lsb already handled
        IO_FLP(LED_PORT, LED);              //flip the pin
    }
}
```

the above section will be installed as the isr.

for any given timing period (TMR_PR), it writes to the timer0 counter only once - when it is initialized at the begining of the timer period, regardless of how long the timing period is - in this case, TMR_PR is a 32-bit type.

after that, tmr0_cnt is updated until the timing duration is exhausted.

the timing error (from loading up TMR0) depends on the chips used / frequency it runs on and compiler mode. about 20 - 30 ticks unoptimized.

here is the code in the user space:

```
tmr0_init(TMR0_PS_1x);                  //reset tmr0 to 1x prescaler, 8-bit
//tmr0_cnt = 0;                         //reset tmr0
tmr0_act(my_isr);                       //install user isr
ei();
```

and here is the simulation:

[image]

TMR_PR is set to F_CPU / 10, or 10 flips per second, as confirmed by the simulation.

The code can be basically ported to any mcu.

Comment: You are saying that, for 8-bit mode, I should load the register only once and it will work forever?

Comment: At the start of the timing cycle, load the 8bit timer with thee lsb of the timing period and zero out the lsb. In thee use, subtract 0x100 from the timing cycle until it reaches zero. Faster implementation can simplify that.